# conditional density of $X$ given $XY^2$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was asked the following problem. Given that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint density $f(x,y)$, find the conditional density of $X$ given $XY^2$.

My thought was to first change variables to $U=X$, $V=XY^2$ to get the joint density of $U$ and $V$, and then use it to write down the conditional density of $U$ given $V$.

The inverse transformation is given by $X=U$, $Y=\sqrt{V/U}$. Calculating the (absolute value of the) determinant of the Jacobian gives $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{UV}}$. So the joint density of $U$ and $V$ is $$f(u,\sqrt{v/u})\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{uv}}$$
Then the conditional density of $U$ given $V$ is
$$f_{U|V}=\frac{\text{joint density of $U$ and $V$}}{\text{marginal of $V$}}=\frac{f(u,\sqrt{v/u})\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{uv}}}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u,\sqrt{v/u})\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{uv}}\,du}=\boxed{\frac{f(u,\sqrt{v/u})\cdot1/\sqrt{u}}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u,\sqrt{v/u})\cdot\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}}}$$
Two questions: is this right, and is this the best that can be done?

This seems like a silly exercise; I don't know what it is trying to test besides the mechanics of change of variables and the definition of the conditional density. Is there anything special about $XY^2$? Is there a larger moral here? I feel as if I must be missing something.